# Parse file with XML scattered throughout

Tags: xml, parsing, prolog, sax

I have a file scattered with XML docs interspersed between normal text, for example

Hello

Xml document

Mary had a little lamb

Xml document

Goodbye

A SAX parser errors on prolog.
Is there any way to parse this and output all the text and elements.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your Xml document is well formed, with appropriate open/close tags (that is, appearing *only* as open/close tags), then a DCG can easily solve your problem, running in 2 'states', in_text and in_xml, and could invoke the full fledged [load_xml](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sgml:load_xml/3)/3 parser when 'exiting' the in_xml state.

Comment: So you suggest Prolog ?
Not used that since University !
Shall look into it.
Thanks

Comment: @user3350288: You tagged the question with `prolog`, thus you received an answer regarding prolog. The question can be answered in probably any programming language, tell us which you prefer / you are familiar with.